# A str value changed over time & Customer dimension(s) in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, logic

I have some customer data over dates and I want to see if for example they choose another product over time. Ideally, i'd like to copy the two columns where the changes occurred into a new column.

So, if I had a table like

```
period, Customer , product
2020-01, Cust1, 12 TS
2020-02, Cust1, 12 TS
2020-03, Cust1, 14 SLM
2020-01, Cust2, 12 SLM
2020-02, Cust2, 12 TS
2020-03, Cust2, 14 SLM
```

So cust1 went over time from TS to SLM, whereas Cust2 went from SLM to TS then the opposite.
The final column should look like:

```
period, Customer , product , change
2020-01, Cust1, 12 TS , NAN
2020-02, Cust1, 12 TS , NAN
2020-03, Cust1, 14 SLM, from TS to SLM
2020-01, Cust2, 12 SLM, NAN
2020-02, Cust2, 12 TS, from SLM to TS
2020-03, Cust2, 14 SLM, from TS to SLM
```

I have look in many solutions avaliable like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42959330/how-to-tell-if-a-value-changed-over-dimensions-in-pandas), but I couldn't manage to do it the way I wanted.

Comment: you missing a column there? why is quantity and product in the same field ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can first `group` the dataframe by `Customer`, then `shift` to check if there is a change. After that we can compare and determine the change.

```py
df['prev_product'] = df.groupby(['Customer'])['product'].shift().bfill()

df['change'] = df[['product', 'prev_product']].apply(lambda x: None if(x[0] == x[1]) else f'from {x[1]}  to {x[0]}', axis=1)
```

```
    period  Customer    n   product prev_product    change
0   2020-01 Cust1       12  TS      TS              None
1   2020-02 Cust1       12  TS      TS              None
2   2020-03 Cust1       14  SLM     TS              from TS to SLM
3   2020-01 Cust2       12  SLM     SLM             None
4   2020-02 Cust2       12  TS      SLM             from SLM to TS
5   2020-03 Cust2       14  SLM     TS              from TS to SLM
​
```

NOTE: `df.drop('prev_product',axis=1)` incase not required.

Comment: no need for `apply` here and don't use `del` use `.df.drop('prev_product',axis=1)`

Answer (score 1):

We can do this in a number of ways, I would suggest using `shift` and `groupby` to find the max record and then `.loc` to filter your query set appropriately.

#### setup.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd


d = """period, Customer, quantity , product
2020-01, Cust1, 12, TS
2020-02, Cust1, 12, TS
2020-03, Cust1, 14, SLM
2020-01, Cust2, 12, SLM
2020-02, Cust2, 12, TS
2020-03, Cust2, 14, SLM"""
```

---

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(d),sep=',',parse_dates=['period'])
# as you have spaces in your csv above.
#df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()

#create a record end date. 
df['period_end_date'] = df.groupby('Customer')['period'].shift(-1)
#find the previous product. 
df.loc[df['period_end_date'].isna(), 
                             'previous_product'] = df.groupby('Customer')['product'].shift(1)
```

---

the current record here will be where the `preiod_end_date` is null.

```
print(df)

      period Customer  quantity product period_end_date previous_product
0 2020-01-01    Cust1        12      TS      2020-02-01              NaN
1 2020-02-01    Cust1        12      TS      2020-03-01              NaN
2 2020-03-01    Cust1        14     SLM             NaT               TS
3 2020-01-01    Cust2        12     SLM      2020-02-01              NaN
4 2020-02-01    Cust2        12      TS      2020-03-01              NaN
5 2020-03-01    Cust2        14     SLM             NaT               TS
```

*if* you need it in a pre-defined format as you've outlined above.

```
df.loc[df['period_end_date'].isna(), 
                            'previous_product'] = ("FROM " 
                            + df.groupby('Customer')['product'].shift(1) 
                            + " TO " 
                            + df['product'] )

      period Customer  quantity product period_end_date  previous_product
0 2020-01-01    Cust1        12      TS      2020-02-01               NaN
1 2020-02-01    Cust1        12      TS      2020-03-01               NaN
2 2020-03-01    Cust1        14     SLM             NaT  FROM  TS TO  SLM
3 2020-01-01    Cust2        12     SLM      2020-02-01               NaN
4 2020-02-01    Cust2        12      TS      2020-03-01               NaN
5 2020-03-01    Cust2        14     SLM             NaT  FROM  TS TO  SLM
```